# Netty Epol workaround bug

Tags: netty, epoll

Lately we used the "-Dorg.jboss.netty.epollBugWorkaround=true" flag in order to enable the workaround of the java 1.6 selector bug.
http://netty.io/news/2012/09/06/3-5-7-final.html

We think that there is a bug in the workaround in netty 3.5.10.

When channel is not connected it iterates over the keys and cancel them.

org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.Boss.run()

```
for (SelectionKey key: selector.keys()) {
SelectableChannel ch = key.channel();
    try {
        if (ch instanceof SocketChannel && !((SocketChannel) ch).isConnected()) {
            notConnected = true;
            // cancel the key just to be on the safe side
            key.cancel();
        }
    } catch (CancelledKeyException e) {
    }
}
```

In such case, when the channel is not connected, it might cancel an event of channel connection failure.

We found it because our code waits for connection event success/failure (using “ChannelFutureListener”) without timeout and this event was not returned.
Our code relies on that the connection event is always returned, whether it is success or failure.

What do you think about the following fix?

```
if (! key.isConnectable() ) {
    key.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Netty code of 3.5.10.

The RegisterTask of the boss is like the following:
    channel.channel.register(boss.selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT, channel);

The key.isConnectable() check is not needed because the events which handled is OP_CONNECT.

So, the fix as far as I understand is to remove the code `key.cancel();`.

Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 0):

I think this makes sense. Could you issue a PR with the fix against latest 3.9 tree.

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.9

Comment: The workaround code in 3.9 is the same as 3.5.
But if you compile the project with java 7 build 12 the selector issue was fixed.